# Translation of "Then open the door"

Tags: traducción, verbos, estados-unidos

I was just in Albuquerque, New Mexico and riding a local bus.  The door had a sign saying (in English and Spanish)

> Wait for Light Then Open Door
>
> Espere la Señal, Luego Habra la Puerta.

Aside from the comma missing in the English text, I am confused about the use of `Haber` instead of `Abrir` in the Spanish text.  To me it seems to say `Then there will be the door` (except that then technically it should be `habrá`).

Is this a mis-translation?  Or a use of `Haber` that I am not familiar with? Or perhaps a regional usage of `Haber`?

[image]

Comment: It is a typo and should be _abra_, as DGaleano pointed in his answer. However... I am tempted to add the [tag:religion] tag and read the sentence in a philosophical way, as if God was about to show us the door to heaven :)

Comment: in that case it should be "habrá" and not "habra"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. "Habrá" means "there will be"

The sign is wrong. The word should be "Abrir"

Also the use of the capitals is incorrect.

Correct alternatives would be:

> Espere la señal luminosa, luego abra la puerta.
>
> Espere (por) la luz y abra la puerta.
>
> Espere que la luz se encienda y abra la puerta.

In any case the correct word is **abra**

Comment: So it is likely that `Habra` is then a typo from `Abra`

Comment: This kind of typo happens to a lot of native-spanish-speaking people, I can't imagine a non-native not getting it wrong too

Comment: @fernando.reyes given that this was in NM its possible that it was created by a native speaker.  Either way the mistake is immortalized on every bus.

Comment: @PeterM It is definitely a typo.

Comment: @fernando.reyes Sorry but I disagree. This does not **happen a lot**. This happens to uneducated people that barely can write or to a non native speaker that is still learning. I personally don't consider this to be a minor mistake. The verb "haber" is a difficult one but the verb "abrir" is one of the easiest.

Comment: @DGaleano I have no idea of the commonality of this type of thing .. but I can image Joe saying "Hey, José.  How do I translate Open the door?", and José replying with "Abra la puerta".  But the typo coming in as Joe mistakenly adding a silent `H` to the front of `Abra` so that it matches up with verbs that actually start with an `H`.  So not so much lack of education, but a brain fart by Joe and no verification by José that Joe got it right. In other words the sort of thing that happens in day to day work in every business.

Comment: @PeterM exactly my point. The person adding the "H" (Joe)  is either a non Spanish speaker or an uneducated native speaker. If the sign was made by José, a native speaker that finished primary school, it would be correct.

Comment: @DGaleano At least now I get an idea of how this typo could have come about.  I never looked at the conjugations of abrir even though I knew abrir should be the verb and haber definitely was not the correct verb.

Comment: also, adding to the Answer : Abra is the imperative for the formal "you" for the verb "abrir"

Answer (score 1):

What was meant was

**Abra** (formal imperative for *abrir*, to open)

Confusion about which words take a silent H and which don't is extremely common among Mexicans, Mexican Americans and Chicanos.  If someone has a little trouble with this aspect of spelling, by no means can we assume the person is ignorant, stupid or uneducated.

There is a certain charm in this sign.  It is written in a natural way, and reads like it was designed by someone bilingual.  A scenario that suggests itself is that the person who wrote it works at the bus company, was raised speaking Spanish at home and some other settings, but had formal schooling primarily or entirely in English.

A native speaker of Spanish will imagine the *sound* of the word and parse it accordingly.  Learners of Spanish understandably lean more on the written letters to figure things out, and might find it confusing.

Regarding the capitalization: In English it's normal to use title case for signs; it's only natural that a bilingual sign carry that over to the Spanish.  See https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/28299/69183 (regarding headings and instructions in websites: "Title case propagates in Spanish pages because it's easier to write and because of the influence of the USA sites").

Comment: Title case is dialect specific in English. To me as a speaker of the dialect of south east England the original English text looks clumsy and odd.

Comment: @mdewey - The signs in your buses would probably look quaint and foreign to visitors from Arizona.  That's what's so fun about languages spoken in more than one country, no?